# Apache Commons - searching inside archives

Tags: java, apache-commons

Is it possible to create IOFileFilter that searches also in *.zip files?

I am looking for all files with *.fot extensions, which part are inside archives.

Maybe is there another simple solution? But I have already written working program and do not want to mess things too much.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to be possible, because the `IOFileFilter` handles the zip-File as what it is - a file. What you could do, is checking the Zip-File by yourself by using `ZipFileEntry`

```
// open a zip file for reading
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("pathToFile.fot");

Enumeration<ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();

while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
    ZipEntry entry = entries.nextElement();

    // get the name of the entry
    String entryName = entry.getName();

    //here do filechecking

}
```